# what is getFieldDecorator in antd and what is the use of getFieldDecorator in React?

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
  initialValue: formData.orderInfo ? formData.orderInfo.netWtUnits : 'MT',
  onChange: e => this.handleUnitsChange(e, 'orderInfo.netWtUnits'),
  rules: [
    {
      required: this.props.contract=="No"?true:false,
      message: 'Please input Weight Units!'
    }
  ]
})(
  <Select placeholder="MT" style={{ width: 55 }}>
    <Select.Option value="MT">MT</Select.Option>
    <Select.Option value="KG">KG</Select.Option>
  </Select>
);
```

**i want to add a default value for this**.can u please help

Comment: can you please post the whole code ?

Comment: According to ant design's [documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/#getFieldDecorator(id,-options)-parameters). getFieldDecorators is a `Two-way binding for form`. There is no getFieldDecorators in React, this is an ant-design API.

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultValue` attribute,

```js
<Select defaultValue="MT"/>
```

Weight options example:

```js
const weightOptions = ["MT", "KG"];

const addWeightOptions = weightOptions =>
  weightOptions.map((weight, i) => (
    <Select.Option key={`${weight}-${i}`} value={weight}>
      {weight}
    </Select.Option>
  ));

<Select
    placeholder="Select Weight Units"
    defaultValue={weightOptions[0]}
  >
    {addWeightOptions(weightOptions)}
</Select>
```

Comment: may i know what can getFieldDecorator will do ?